# Preserve NTFS permsions while copy from windows to samba?

Tags: backup, ntfs, file-permissions

Ηellow Everybody,
I have this huge nightmare between windows ntfs and samba share. I am using the samba share mostly for backup data to format and then copy back their data. For this process i am usning total comander with the " copy NTFS permisions active". Copying from windows to samba is completed everytime without problems. The problem start when i have to copu back the data to the new instalation of winodws.There most of the times can not copy almost nothing due to  "Access denied Error" . Seams to be copying from windows to samba ha make the ntfs persmisions to disapear. The only painfull way is to "take ownership" of these files in order to copy them back.So i dont know if there is configuration that can preserve these ntfs permissions while backup them in samba.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What operating system is hosting the Samba share?  If it is Windows.. why are you calling it a "samba share".. if it isn't Windows.. then there isn't any support for NTFS access control lists using Windows credentials.

Comment: If the host is Linux see this>>>https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/preserve-file-permissions-when-copying-from-ntfs-to-a-samba-share-170575/